# How to shorten my two methods?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

So I have written two methods, one to find the most frequent digit in an array, another to find the most common name in an array. Both of which are extremely convoluted.

***I understand how to go about each question but I am not sure how to condense my methods. Also, I am not allowed to use array methods***.

> First, the most common digit method.

```
 public static int mostFrequentDigit(int[] a){
    int count0=0, count1=0, count2=0, count3=0, count4=0, count5=0, count6=0, count7=0, count8=0, count9=0;
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     int digit=a[i]%10;
     if (digit=0) count0++;
      else if (digit=1) count1++;
      else if (digit=2) count2++;
      else if (digit=3) count3++;
      else if (digit=4) count4++;
      else if (digit=5) count5++;
      else if (digit=6) count6++;
      else if (digit=7) count7++;
      else if (digit=8) count8++;
      else count9++;
    }
    if (count0> count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9);
     return count0;
    if (count1>count0, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9);
     return count1;
    if (count2>count0, count1, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9);
     return count2;
    if (count3>count0, count1, count2, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9);
     return count3;
    if (count4>count0, count1, count2, count3, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9);
     return count4;
    if (count5>count0, count1, count2, count3, count4, count6, count7, count8, count9);
     return count5
    if (count6>count0, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count7, count8, count9);
     return count6;
    if (count7>count0, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6, count8, count9);
     return count7;
    if (count8>count0, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count9);
     return count8;
    else 
     return count9;
}}
```

> Now, the most common name method.

```
public static String mostCommonName (String[] names) {
     int indexOfFrequency = 0;
     int indexOfMostFrequency = 0;
     String mostCommon = "";
     int frequency = 1;
     int mostFrequency = 1;
     for (int index = 0; index < names.length; index ++) {
       indexOfFrequency = index;
      for (int scan = index + 1; scan < names.length; scan ++) {
        if ((names[scan].compareTo(names[index])) == (0)) {
          indexOfFrequency = scan;
          frequency ++;
        }
      }
      if (frequency > mostFrequency) {
        mostFrequency = frequency;
        mostCommon = names[indexOfFrequency];
        indexOfMostFrequency = indexOfFrequency;
      }
      else if (frequency == mostFrequency) {
        if ((names[indexOfFrequency].compareTo(names[indexOfMostFrequency]))   < 0) {
          mostCommon = names[indexOfFrequency];
          indexOfMostFrequency = indexOfFrequency;
        }
        else {
          mostCommon = names[indexOfMostFrequency];
        }
      }
      frequency = 1;
    }
    return mostCommon;
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Map` for both. Iterate over the characters of a String representation of the digits, or the names themselves, and store occurrences in a `HashMap`.

Comment: Dont put each line as code do it as a whole by selecting all your code as a chunk and pressing `ctrl+k`

Comment: sorry I forgot to explain the two methods. most common digit takes the most common digit in an entire array i.e. [1234, -90, 80, -45675].  This array has 2 0's, 4's, and 5's, and 1 of each of the other digits, so the result should be the integer (not array) 540. As for the most common name, it takes an array such as {"fred" "wilma" "fred" "fred"} and returns fred, hence the name, most common name.

Comment: @JackWilliams that's actually what I did, I'm not sure why it turned out that way.

Comment: @Kon I haven't been introduced to Map and HashMap yet actually, could you explain, or show me what you mean?

Comment: Your first method has a **lot** of bugs. Equality testing is done with `==` (`=` is assignment). And the comma in an `if` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @SSBM For Map and HahMap info, refer the official tutorial here -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: As an aside, you are aware that you compare numbers with == and that you cannot compare a number to a comma-separated list of numbers, right?  I assume this is pseudo-code?

Comment: @Thevenin Yeah sorry I also forgot to mention that I didn't write that code out fully(it is just so long and I got lazy so I wrote it shorthand so I could change it later). also thanks for the Map and HashMap info!@BalwinderSingh

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to consider the least significant digit you can do this.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1};
int mostCommon = IntStream.of(a)
         // get the lowest digit
        .mapToObj(i -> i % 10)
        // create a mapping of digits => count of digits
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
        // take the entries
        .entrySet().stream()
        // sort them by count, descending.
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue()))
        // give me the first result.
        .findFirst()
        // if there was no result, throw an error.
        .orElseThrow(AssertionError::new)
        // give me the digit.
        .getKey();

System.out.println(mostCommon);
```

prints

```
1
```

If you want all the digits for an Integer you need to write a method to return a Stream of all he digits and use `.flatMap()`

In the case of names, the code is the same except you need `Stream.of(a).collect...`

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer the digit counting question first. Your code seems to only look at the least significant digit. You need to find all digits in each integer before counting them.

Here is a possible solution using Java 8 streams:

```
Optional<Integer> mostCommonDigit(int[] numbers) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers)
        .flatMap(this::streamDigits)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}

private Stream<Integer> streamDigits(int number) {
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
    while (number > 0) {
        digits.add(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    return digits.stream();
}
```

It returns an `Optional` to cope with an empty array.